# SafariDriver is not responding after opening a URL

Tags: webdriver, safaridriver

I am trying to run [SafariDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver) to automate google pages.
What I find is the driver opens the URL and loads the home page, but after that the driver is not responding and WebDriver is timing out.

Lines of code that are executing:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");
//driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("webdriver")
```

I am getting console output :

> Jun 27, 2012 10:06:33 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer
>   start INFO: Server started at  Jun 27, 2012 10:06:38 AM
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverWebSocketHandler onOpen INFO:
>   Connection opened Jun 27, 2012 10:06:39 AM
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverWebSocketHandler onMessage
>   INFO: Received message:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"browserName":"safari","version":"","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true},"id":"78f7f1aa-8d4d-4d6b-8cc4-a58eb96bf3e2"}
>   Jun 27, 2012 10:06:39 AM
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverConnection onMessage INFO:
>   Processing message:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"browserName":"safari","version":"","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true},"id":"78f7f1aa-8d4d-4d6b-8cc4-a58eb96bf3e2"}
>   Jun 27, 2012 10:09:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer
>   stop INFO: Stopping server Jun 27, 2012 10:09:39 AM
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverWebSocketHandler onClose INFO:
>   Connection closed

How can I get back the driver control and resume the rest of execution from line
`System.out.println(driver.getTitle());`?

Comment: Rakesh - What happens if you comment out the System.out.println(driver.getTitle());?  Does the rest of the code execute?

Comment: @DanSnell, No nothing executes after .get() opens the urls. Its like no response comes to webdriver after driver.get() executes. I tried giving different commands after driver.get().

Comment: As i opened the web inspector and checked in console. It was saying command inactive after opening url. Also I tried with different websites or urls.

Comment: Its working now, was a mistake on my part.

Comment: Rakesh - Great to hear you got it working.  Could you post your resolution below so that if other folks run into a similar problem they might be able to use what you figured out to resolve their issue?

Comment: Its working now.  I was using safari extension of 2.21 build and selenium server jar of 2.21. Now updated to both extension and jar file of 2.24 release .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now.
I had  problem with Selenium standalone server jars.
I just created new Safari extension with latest code and used Selenium standalone server 2.24. Now it is working fine, I believe it was  some version issue.